# Scrapy, How to still get the content with status 302 (redirecting)

Tags: python, search, scrapy, web-crawler

this is my simple spider code (just started):

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

with browser I can access the url 'http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all' normally. But why with this scrapy I get 302 response, and I fail to crawling the page..

please anyone tell me, how to fix it..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the webpage is expecting some cookies, if those cookies are not found it redirects to index page.

I got it working by adding these cookies: `js_enabled=true; is_cookie_active=true;`:

```
$scrapy shell "http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all"
# redirect happens
>[1]: response.url
<[1]: 'http://www.liputan6.com'
# add cookie to request:
>[2]: request.headers['Cookie'] = 'js_enabled=true; is_cookie_active=true;'
>[3]: fetch(request)
# redirect no longer happens
>[4]: response.url
<[4]: 'http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all'
```

Edit: For your code try:

```
 def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        req= scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
        req.headers['Cookie'] = 'js_enabled=true; is_cookie_active=true;'
        yield req

def parse(self, response):   
    # 200 response here
```

Comment: hi @Granitosaurus thanks for your advice, 
I  run scrapy from script, http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

where I add the code "cookie"?

Comment: hi again, I have try your advice, but I get 2017-08-08 07:15:58 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.liputan6.com> from <GET http://www.liputan6.com/search?q=bubarkan+hti&type=all>
2017-08-08 07:15:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.liputan6.com> (referer: None). I still get redirect 302

Comment: But for me, even console not allowing to pass any cache inputs . How to do the same in settings.py file ?